# What is the most probable location of the particle at $t=0$?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, wavefunction, probability

Am I supposed to determine the most probable location of the particle by its graph of the wavefunction alone? The way I would do that is to imagine it being squared. I do so by imagining each point on the curve being squared, which leads me to perceive a "hill" that grows and decays exponentially. Therefore, the most probable location of finding the particle would be at $x=a$. Please tell me if **any** part of this reasoning is incorrect.

**The question (I'm asking about part C):**

[image]

---

**The answer:**

[image]

Comment: Your reasoning is correct--by squaring the wavefunction you get the probability. At $x=a$, we can obviously see that $\psi$ and therefore $|\psi|^2$ will be at a maximum. Thus, the particle will most likely be found at $x=a$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest way to see it, is the following: The particle is most likely to be found where the probability is the greatest. The probability of finding a particle in the interval $[x, x+dx]$ is $|\Psi(x, t)|^2dx$. Thus, the most likely position is where $|\Psi(x, t)|^2$ is maximum. Ie, in $x=a$ for $t=0$.